# using NAS Server as MySQL DB server?

Tags: mysql, database, network-attached-storage

we are small web develepment company with 4-5 workstations. We use one of the PCs as a webserver and DB server. We are considering option to buy some NAS server (like http://www.synology.com/products/product.php?product_name=DS212j&lang=enu) to use it as DB and webserver. As i dont have any expirince in this field, i would ask is this wise? will this cope with the complex and more dempanding sql queries as we test projects on the local environment? Or maybe will it be wiser to buy another PC and install only OS and WAMP/LAMP on it?

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would highly advise against using a NAS for anything else than a file server. The only way you can tell if it would cope is by actually doing it - but I would reccomend a dedicated machine for this. The HP ProLiant MicroServer could be a choice, same price range currently, and comes with a dual-core 1.5Ghz CPU, 2GB RAM and a 250GB HDD.

Comment: I realize this was answered 9 years ago, so its quite outdated. my NAS is a Synology DS920+ with 8GB of RAM and 32TB of storage (before raid settings). It can run docker images, so totally suitable for a MySQL server

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to run a development database on a relatively slow CPU and 256MB RAM.

You should get a dedicated box for that and put Windows with XAMPP or more preferably Linux with the server roles you need on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to actually use your database, its very unwise. If you are suggesting that you will only use the NAS for mounting filesystemsthat your databases will be stored on, thats a bad idea too. Decent spec computers are very much a commodity right now, I think its a false economy to skimp on these resources.

Comment: why do you say that using the NAS only for the filesystem that the db is on is also a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good idea for less than 4 concurrent user using a Atom 2701 based NAS if you are using it as a test database server for less than 4 concurrent users.

Atom is getting more and more popular in NAS. The dual core + HT architecture is capable to support 4 concurrent user. You may search for **How Multi-Core Processors Accelerate your LAMP Applications** to know why 4 concurrent user is good for Atom 2701 when you are using Apache with pre-fork.

Armada XP dual SoC is not commend because it may support only 2 concurrent session in the same configuration.

You might also need to consider about security for remote connection. Please read **[Using NAS as your Database Server](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/using-nas-as-your-database-server/)** to enable remote connection, grant privilege, and harden your NAS.

If you are not satisfied with the performance, you may launch memcached on NAS and load Memcache.so or Memcached.so on client to have your LAMP programs utilize database cache. Search for **Optimize Synology DSM for ZurmoCRM** for my test result from 34 to 10 seconds by the help of memcached on ZurmoCRM.

PHP accelerator will help, too. Please install them on your client. When I mentioned about client, I mean where your PHP program are interpreted or executed.

I have create a [**performance report using SugarCRM on QNAP TS-119PII and TS-269L**](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/qnap-ts-119pii-and-ts-269l-as-a-mysql-database-server-performance-report/). For single user, TS-119PII is better to be used as a database server than running SugarCRM. TS-269L seems no big different between them.

When there are more concurrent users, the difference between TS-119PII and TS-269L should become more noticeable. Based on the hardware architecture of D2701, 4 concurrent user is the best scenario for TS-269L.